# css Hover для движущегося элемента

Tags: css, css3

```css
div {   
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: transform 2s;                
}
div:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);                               
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <div></div>
    </body>        
</html>
```

Есть блок, хотелось бы сделать, чтобы при наведении мышки он крутился, и когда мышка уходит с его начального состояния, крутился обратно. Проблема в том, что когда он начинает крутиться, его края сдвигаются, и даже если мышка не двигалась, она находится уже не над ним, и, видимо, происходит mouseover(). Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: а код можете выложить

Comment: Выложите пожалуйста код. Кроме css что-то можно использовать?

Comment: @newman нет, только css

Comment: @Sergalas выложил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать так.

Т.е. основная идея в том что реагирует на наведение курсора внешний элемент, а крутиться внутренний.

```css
div {   
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: transform 2s;                
}
div > div {
 background-color: red;
}
div:hover > div {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);                               
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <div><div></div></div>
    </body>        
</html>
```